# Where does Microsoft Outlook for Office 365 save Profiles Info?

Tags: c#, windows, outlook, office365, desktop

I'm creating a program on a C# which works with Outlook desktop client. I need to get all profiles added to Outlook.

I found that Outlook saves this info in the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Profiles\`

But on the computers in my organization, we don't have this key, searching was stopped on `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\`

In Outlook, I added a few email addresses and set default signatures. So we have this info somewhere but I can't find it.

Someone knows an alternative place or way how I can get this profile info.

We use Microsoft Outlook for Office 365 MSO(16.0.12325.20280) 32-bit.

Comment: How about monitoring Registry access with [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) and find out by yourself?

Answer (score 1):

Outlook 2013 and up:

`Software\Microsoft\Office\<version>\Outlook\Profiles` - where `<version>` is the Outlook version (e.g. 16.0 for Outlook 2016)

Older versions of Outlook (2010 and older):

`Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging` Subsystem\Profiles

Windows Store version of Outlook (no longer being installed). Note that it is virtualized and is inaccessible from outside of the outlook.exe address space.

```
Software\Microsoft\Office\<version>\Outlook\Profiles_AppX
```